# $o\notin \mathbb R$ and $\infty\notin\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, infinitesimals

$o$ denotes infinitesimal

In classic analysis $o\notin \mathbb R$ and $\infty\notin\mathbb R$

Because the completeness of real number, there are no gaps between real numbers. Denote the real number right after $0$ as $r$, then:

Is $1/r\in \mathbb R$?

Is $r/2\in \mathbb R$?

Comment: What is "little $o$" in this instance? Also, there isn't generally a notion of "the real number right after $0$."

Comment: In classical analysis, $0 \in \mathbb R$, if by $o$ you meant to write $0$.

Comment: There is no "number right after 0" because the real numbers have no gaps, as you've said. So what is the question?

Comment: Since $\mathbb{R}$ is dense in itself, for all numbers $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, if $x < y$, there is a number $z \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x < z$ and $z < y$. So between "the number after 0" and 0 there is another number, and between those, etc.

If you're talking about infinitesimals, there's an infinite number of those between every number, and an infinite number of infinitesimals between each infinitesimal, etc.

Comment: What is the "real number right after 0"?

Comment: $o$ is infinitesimal

Comment: There are no infinitesimals in the real numbers. Interestingly, even in nonstandard models of the reals that DO contain infinitesimals, there is STILL no smallest number after zero, and for the same reason. You can divide any positive real, standard or nonstandard, by 2. Any model of the axioms of the reals is a field.

Comment: @user4894, the claim that there are no infinitesimals in the real numbers depends on specific choices of a foundational theory you are working in.  If you are working in Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory then this is correct.  But in [Internal Set Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_set_theory) you find infinitesimals in the ordinary real line itself.

Comment: @Hi GPA, could you try to clarify your question?

Comment: @MikhailKatz I don't think bringing internal set theory is going to be helpful to the OP. Clearly they are referring to the real line as defined and understood by the vast majority of the mathematical community (the unique complete Archimedean ordered field, or an equivalent definition). Also, while it does make reference to a certain amount of set theory, this definition long precedes ZF and is (quantifiably) vastly more basic; I think that implying that it's ZF-dependent is disingenuous, and stands a good chance of confusing the OP further. (cont'd)

Comment: Besides, I think "In IST, there are infinitesimal reals," while accurate, reflects the dubious role of the set $\mathbb{R}$ in IST: IST proves that $\mathbb{R}$ is not Archimedean ($\exists r\in\mathbb{R}\forall q\in\mathbb{Q}_{>0}(st(q)\implies r<q)$), so in a sense it knows that its $\mathbb{R}$ is not what is usually meant by "the reals." This reflects a divide in how to think about a model of IST: as "bigger" than a ZF-model (the internal part), or as a class structure inside a model of ZF (e.g. an expansion of $\prod V/\mathcal{U}$ for some non-countably-closed ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$).

Comment: (Whoops, that should read "$\exists r\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$" of course.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber, the reals are still the unique complete Archimedean ordered field in IST, as well, as per "the vast majority of the mathematical community" as you put it.   Contrary to what you write, IST does *not* prove that $\mathbb R$ is nonarchimedean in the usual sense of the term "archimedean" in ZFC, which obviously does *not* enable the use of the "st" predicate.  I stand by my remarks concerning a veiled commitment to the details of a particular set theory. This does not mean that I don't find that theory useful; on the contrary.  Most of my 60 or so research articles and a book...

Comment: ...are concerned with a ZFC framework only.

Comment: @MikhailKatz "I stand by my remarks concerning a veiled commitment to the details of a particular set theory." I don't understand this; the infinitesimal-free real line long predates ZF, or anything like ZF. E.g. I believe Principia Mathematica also doesn't have infinitesimal reals in any sense, and that's an extremely different theory from ZF (New Foundations also works here, but is anachronistic). The "common intuition" between the two is quite limited, and I don't think there's any meaningful sense in which a commitment to this intuition can constitute a commitment to a specific set theory.

Comment: I believe Frege's Grundgezetze also didn't accommodate infinitesimals; now of course, that system was inconsistent, but by virtue of having a coherent intuitive motivation which is fundamentally different from that of ZF it demonstrates again that there is no veiled commitment to ZF in excluding infinitesimals from the real line. Finally, of course, there's the issue that most mathematicians would say there are no infinitesimal reals, but also couldn't state the ZF axioms if pressed, and probably haven't heard of the cumulative hierarchy; in what sense, then, are they committed to ZF?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I am genuinely interested in this discussion.  Note however that the topic of the discussion seems to be shifting to history.  You are probably aware of the fact that I have a certain amount of expertise in the area.  I would be interested in discussing claims such as "the infinitesimal-free line long predates ZF" so long as we are willing to base such a discussion on  historical evidence rather than received ideas. Come to think of it, this may make an interesting separate *question*. I am open to your suggestions as to how to proceed.

Comment: @MikhailKatz I have to go sleep right now (it's 2am in my time zone), but I would also be interested in continuing this conversation. I don't think it would make a good MO/MSE post, since it really is a conversation, but I'd be happy to conduct it over email (as long as you forgive me for my late responses); and I'm happy to let you publicly post any responses I make if that makes things more satisfactory (subject to usual clauses about quoting in appropriate context, etc. etc.). My email can be found on my profile page here. EDIT: apparently it's not on my profile, but it's findable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, an issue at the beginning. I don't know what your "$o$" represents. If it's supposed to denote "$0$" (zero), then you are incorrect: $0$ **is** a real number. EDIT: You clarify that $o$ is an infinitesimal. In that case, what you've written is correct - no infinitesimal is a real number - although it's slightly misleading, since it suggests that there is some *specific* infinitesimal called "$o$." In fact, even in [the infinitesimals as usually construed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis), there is no "smallest infinitesimal" after zero: we can always divide $o$ by $2$, as with real numbers.

---

More to the point, this question is founded on an incorrect assumption. When you write " Denote the real number right after $0$ as $r$," you are assuming that there *is such* a real number. (Think about if I said "Denote the biggest real number as $s$" - that'd be wrong of me, since there *isn't* a biggest real number!)

In fact, you're close to the *proof* that there is no such number: from the basic axioms for the real numbers, we can show that if $x$ is a real number then so is ${x\over 2}$, and if $x>0$ then $0<{x\over 2}<x$. (This is why you're finding it confusing to think about ${r\over 2}$ - it's clear that that should be between $0$ and $r$, despite what you've assumed $r$ is!)
So there is no "real number right after $0$" (or right after anything else, for that matter). Indeed, this is (part of) what is meant by " there are no gaps between real numbers."

Comment: $o$ denotes infinitesimal

Comment: Couple of things, though: infinitesimals are are part of nonstandard analysis, they're not real numbers, and there isn't just one infinitesimal number greater than 0 but smaller than all other real numbers, there's uncountably many of 'em.

Comment: @HighGPA I've edited to reflect this. The important point, however, is the assumption you make about there being a "next real number" - do you understand why this is flawed?